ProxyPassMatch not working to redirect user
When I attempt to access https://example1.com/xyz/services/ERx?token=12345 then I want it should serve from  https://example2.com/redirectRx?token=12345.
ServerName example1.com:443

ProxyPassMatch "^/xyz/services/ERx(.*)$" "https://example2.com/redirectRx$1"

